# Thread Safety with SSL + NIO

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, nio

There is some helpful information available on implementing the `SSL` with `NIO (SocketChannel and SSLEngine)` using java, not using a framework such as netty etc.

I am trying to come up with an `SSL` implementation that could work with `blocking/non` blocking channels and got some basic `qns`.

There is not much info on the issues to be dealt with thread safety, when the appData and Net buffers are being manipulated. Per the documentation of `SSLEngine`,

"There are two concurrency issues to be aware of:

The `wrap()` and `unwrap()` methods may execute concurrently of each other.

The `SSL/TLS` protocols employ ordered packets. Applications must take care to ensure that generated packets are delivered in sequence. If packets arrive out-of-order, unexpected or fatal results may occur."

Would this be applicable to both blocking and non blocking ? Could somebody explain. thanks.

Also, the general recommendation for setting up the initial buffer sizes seems to based of (`session.getApplicationBufferSize()/getPacketBufferSize()`), how would these values be set ? Are these better to be used instead of some standard buffer size of `32k` or so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You won't normally be doing `SSLEngine` operations in multiple threads so the question should not arise. The only time you would use another thread would be when executing `SSLEngine` tasks, and that doesn't use the `SSLEngine`.

> Would this be applicable to both blocking and non blocking?

2. Yes, of course.

> the general recommendation for setting up the initial buffer sizes seems to based of (`session.getApplicationBufferSize()/getPacketBufferSize())`, how would these values be set?

3. Set your network buffer sizes to `getPacketBufferSize()`, and your application buffer sizes to `getApplicationBufferSize()`.

> Are these better to be used instead of some standard buffer size of 32k or so?

4. You can use different buffer sizes if you like, but why? You run the risk of either wasting space with buffers that are too big, or providing buffers that are too small to be usable.

Comment: Thanks @EJP.  As usual, you comments on this topic are very helpful. Could you pls. elaborate on the mentioned possible concurrency issue, as usually I dont see, these being explicitly handled :

"The wrap() and unwrap() methods may execute concurrently of each other.

The SSL/TLS protocols employ ordered packets. Applications must take care to ensure that generated packets are delivered in sequence. If packets arrive out-of-order, unexpected or fatal results may occur."  Should this be handled explicitly in the Client instantiating the SSLEngine ?

Comment: 'May execute concurrently of each other' means that *you* can execute them concurrently. If you only use one thread, which is the whole point of NIO, there is no packet-sequence issue to handle.

Comment: Final Clarification Pls.(hopefully), Again from SSLEngine documentation:  "By separating the SSL/TLS abstraction from the I/O transport mechanism, the SSLEngine can be used for a wide variety of I/O types, such as non-blocking I/O (polling), selectable non-blocking I/O, Socket and the traditional Input/OutputStreams, local ByteBuffers or byte arrays, .."  Does that mean that SSLEngine could be used in transport other than NIO, i.e regular sockets ? Wasnt SSLSocket to be used for SSL with regular socket based blocking IO and SSLEngine for NIO (blocking IO)

Comment: @KrishnaMothukuri Yes, you could use the `SSLEngine` with ordinary `Sockets`, with some difficulty. Not much point though. To me the `SSLEngine` design was a bit of a cop-out. They could have provided an `SSLSocketChannel` instead, or as well. Most of the reasons advanced for not doing so don't hold water.